# Bash command to read a line based on the parameters I pass - perform column-based lookups

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, lookup

I have a file links.txt:

```
1 a.sh
3 b.sh
6 c.sh
4 d.sh
```

So, if i pass 1,4 as parameters to another file(master.sh), a.sh and d.sh should be stored in a variable.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please post your first attempt at doing this.

Comment: LB is line break `cat file |while read line` LB `do` . It iterates through all the lines of file, but i want line to be read based on the parameters.

Comment: `sed '3!d' links.txt` this gives me third line of the file

Comment: Note that the question doesn't specify whether the results must reflect the _argument_ order, or whether returning results in the order in which the lookup numbers occur in the _file_ is acceptable.
For instance, must argument list `6 1` result in `c.sh` and `a.sh` (in that order), or is it OK to return `a.sh` before `c.sh`, because ID `1` happens to come before `6` in the file?
I've tagged the existing answers to clarify which of the two solutions they implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loops through each argument and greps for it in the links file. The result is piped into cut where we specify the delimiter as a space with -d flag and the field number as 2 with -f flag. Finally this is appended to the array called files.

```
links="links.txt"
files=()

for arg in $@; do
    files=("${files[@]}" `grep "^$arg" "$links" | cut -d" " -f2`)
done;

echo ${files[@]}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./master.sh 1 4
a.sh d.sh
```

Edit:
As pointed out by mklement0, the solution above reads the file once per arg. The following first builds the pattern then reads the file just once.

```
links="links.txt"
pattern="^$1\s"
for arg in ${@:2}; do
    pattern+="|^$arg\s"
done
files=$(grep -E "$pattern" "$links" | cut -d" " -f2)
echo ${files[@]}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./master.sh 1 4
a.sh d.sh
```

Comment: This answer preserves the _argument_ order in the results (see comment on the question).

Comment: Kudos for a solution that preserves the argument order in the results - albeit at the expense of reading the file once for every argument.
Though not an issue with the sample data, it is worth noting that the results of the command substitution aren't only subject to word-splitting (as desired), but also to _globbing_.
To promote good habits, I suggest using modern syntax `$(…)` instead of `\`…\``.

Comment: I appreciate the update, but note that your 2nd solution no longer preserves the argument order in the results. Aside from that, `grep -f <(printf "^%s\n" "$@") "$links" | cut -d' ' -f2` would make for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

`sed '3!d'` would print the 3rd line, but not the line that starts with `3`. For that, you need `sed '/^3 /!d'`. The problem is you can't combine them for more lines, as this means "Delete everything that doesn't start with a 3", which means all other lines will be missed. So, use `sed -n '/^3 /p'` instead, i.e. don't print by default and tell sed what lines to print, not what lines to delete.

You can loop over the argument and create a sed script from them that prints the lines, then run `sed` using this output:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
shift

for id in "$@" ; do
    echo "/^$id /p"
done | sed -nf- "$file"
```

Run as `script.sh filename 3 4`.

If you want to remove the id from the output, you can either use

```
cut -f2 -d' '
```

or you can modify the generated sed script to do the work

```
echo "/^$id /s/.* //p"
```

i.e. only print if the substitution was successful.

Comment: Hi, thanks @choroba. When i pass 3 4 its displaying `3 b.sh` and `4 d.sh`, but i  want to eliminate 3 and 4 and just store `b.sh` and `d.sh` in a variable or an array.

Comment: This answer returns the results in _file_ order (see comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

The following **`awk` solution**:

- **preserves the argument order**; that is, the results reflect the order in which the lookup values were specified (as opposed to the order in which the lookup values happen to occur in the file).

  - If that is not important (i.e., if outputting the results in *file* order is acceptable), the `readarray` technique below can be combined with this one-liner, which is a generalized variant of [Panta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300024/45375):
    `grep -f <(printf "^%s\n" "$@") links.txt | cut -d' ' -f2-`
- **performs well**, because the input file is only read *once*; the only requirement is that all key-value pairs fit into memory as a whole (as a single associative Awk array (dictionary)).
- **works with any lookup values** that **don't have embedded whitespace**.

  - Similarly, the assumption is that the *output* column values (containing values such as `a.sh` in the sample input) have no embedded whitespace. `awk` doesn't handle quoted fields well, so more work would be needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t files < <(
  awk -v idList="$*" '
    BEGIN { count=split(idList, idArr); for (i in idArr) idDict[idArr[i]]++ }
    $1 in idDict { idDict[$1] = $2 }
    END { for (i=1; i<=count; ++i) print idDict[idArr[i]] }
  ' links.txt
)

# Print results.
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

- `readarray -t files` reads stdin input (`<`) line by line into array variable `files`.

  - Note: `readarray` requires Bash v4+; on Bash 3.x, such as on macOS, replace this part with
    `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra files`
- `<(...)` is a Bash [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that, loosely speaking, presents the output from the enclosed command as if it were (self-deleting) temporary file.

  - This technique allows `readarray` to run in the *current shell* (as opposed to a *subshell* if a pipeline had been used), which is necessary for the `files` variable to remain defined in the remainder of the script.
- The `awk` command breaks down as follows:

  - `-v idList="$*"` passes the space-separated list of all command-line arguments as a single string to *Awk* variable `idList`.

    - Note that this assumes that the arguments have no *embedded* spaces, which is indeed the case here and also generally the case with identifiers.
  - `BEGIN { ... }` is only executed *once*, before the individual lines are processed:

    - `split(idList, idArr)` splits the input ID list into an array by whitespace and stores the result in `idArr`.
    - `for (i in idArr) idDict[idArr[i]]++ }` then converts the (conceptually regular) array into *associative* array `idDict` (dictionary), whose keys are the input IDs - this enables efficient lookup by ID later, and also allows storing the lookup *result* for each ID.
  - `$1 in idDict { idDict[$1] = $2 }` is processed for every input line:

    - Pattern `$1 in idDict` returns true if the line's first whitespace-separated field (`$1`) - e.g., `6` - is among the keys (`in`) of associative array `idDict`, and, if so, executes the associated action (`{...}`).
    - Action `{ idDict[$1] = $2 }` then assigns the second field (`$2`) - e.g., `c.sh` - to the `iDict` entry for key `$1`.
  - `END { ... }` is executed *once*, *after* all input lines have been processed:

    - `for (i=1; i<=count; ++i) print idDict[idArr[i]]` loops over all input IDs *in order* and prints each ID's lookup result, which is the *value* of the dictionary entry with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example with grep and cut:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $(grep "$1\|$2" links.txt|cut -d' ' -f2)
do
    echo $line
done
```

Example of usage:

```
./master.sh 1 4
a.sh
d.sh
```

Comment: This answer returns the results in _file_ order (see comment on the question).

Comment: A promising approach, assuming the argument order needn't be preserved, but it's fair to assume that the use of _2_ arguments is just an example, and that a generic solution is desired, so I suggest `grep -f <(printf "^%s\n" "$@") links.txt | cut -d' ' -f2`.
Please generally [do not use `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), even though it happens to work with the specific sample input.
You can read the results into an array with a `while` loop, or, as requested by the OP, into a array variable with `readarray -t files < <(…)` (Bash v4+).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stores the values and call them at will:

```
items=()

while read -r num file
do
  items[num]="$file"
done<links.txt

for arg
do
  echo "${items[arg]}"
done
```

Now you can use the items array any time you like :)

Comment: An viable solution with the sample input, but there are two caveats with respect to _generalizing_ it:
(a) it only works with ID values that are positive integers, (b) performance will be an issue with large input files: Bash loops are sloooow,
and you don't want to read all data into memory as a whole.